# Netbeans Restfull tutorial test runs but result are different and can not test properly

Tags: java, web-services, rest, netbeans, jax-rs

I read the nebeans tutorial for RESTfull service (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) and tried to implement it. But when i'm run the test I'm not getting the screen what they say. I found that some say it is a bug on netbeans  whilst some say it is bug on browser.I read some related question on this site but could not get much help

[image]

Suppose to appear as previous one

but appear as following one....

[image]

Note that navigation is not appears.
I'm unable to get the test it further. 
I'm using netbeans 7.1 bundle 
Can any one help me out. Thank you.

p.s : This page opens as reading a file( file:///home/xxx/xxx )

Comment: I had the same issue. If I remember well (but I am not 100% sure) it was browser-related. Which browsers have you tried?

Comment: I'm on linux platform. I tried firefox, Chrome and opera. Nothing is working!

Comment: Ok. So I suggest to use FireBug and proceed manually.

Comment: I getting this error.  
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldRest/resources/application.wadl. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
test-resbeans.js:1334Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined...
How can I proceed ?

Comment: You should start posting some code.

Comment: Please describe more. I don't understand what you just told!

Comment: @perissf The problem is that it is no longer supported on Firefox Quantum. Then what else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial dose't work on that way. When we test the restfull test we need to brows and give that restfull service. Then it will work on any browser.(I guess to test it need a service).

Comment: Could you please give more details? I have the same issue. I can't figure out how to make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

In that link you can notice the caution

Caution: For later versions of Firefox, you need to generate the test client in another Java web application than the service project.

I got the same error in firefox and chrome, then I tried test-resbeans.html in IE and its working fine as mentioned.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work in any browser. :( Moreover, firebug is not supported in Firefox Quantum. Is there some other workaround for nowadays?